# Recovering Unique Factorization

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can a (commutative) ring $S$ fail to have unique factorization but be a subring of a (possibly noncommutative) ring $R$ which does have unique factorization?

The idea being that the irreducibles in $S$ split further when viewed as a subring of $R$, thus somehow recovering unique factorization. It probably makes sense to require that the notion of unique factorization in $R$ reduces to the one in $S$.

Comment: As given in the answers, when $S$ is a domain one can accomplish this by localization. Perhaps one should then consider the a minimal multiplicative set $M$ for which $S_M$ is a UFD. I do not know if such a thing has been studied, it seems like it could potentially be interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any domain which is not a UFD; then it is a subring of its field of fractions, which is a UFD.

Comment: While true, it seems like when you're actually trying to do something this is unhelpful as it simply makes everything non-zero a unit, and sheds no light on any factorization structure (obviously not a full UFD structure by hypothesis) present in $S$.

Comment: This is true, but for example $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ can be enlarged to a UFD by considering $\mathbb{Z}[ \omega]$ for $\omega$ a cube root of unity. One can still recover quite a bit of information from this because the group of units is still fairly small.

Comment: @JHance sorry to have deleted my comment-- I realized that it was not very accurate, since irreducible elements in $S$ can become reducible in $R$, of course.

Comment: is enlarging  the group of units really the only possibility (to recover unique factorization)?

Comment: @vuur, it's certainly not. I didn't think that through before posting the comment, hence the deletion. You can either create more units, or change the set of irreducible elements. That is, perhaps $a=xy=x'y'$ are two distinct irreducible factorizations in $S$. Then either this is *not* an irreducible factorization in $R$, or the factors are associate in $R$ (the latter option corresponds to "adding units," and was the only one I originally thought about).

Comment: Ok, one more question. I imagine $rs\ tu=xy=a=x'y'=rt\ su$. But what if $R$ is noncommutative. Then this example won't work. Is enlarging the group of units then the only choice?

Comment: @vuur, unfortunately I'm not familiar with factorization in non-comm rings. In fact, I've only seen irreducibility defined for integral domains. If you don't mind, what is the definition you were thinking of using for irreducibility and uniqueness of factorization if $R$ is non-commutative?

Comment: Something along the lines of this: [Factorization of Hurwitz Quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hurwitz_quaternion#Factorization_into_irreducible_elements)

Comment: OK, so we'll say that an element is irreducible if it is not $0$ or a unit, and cannot be written as a product of non-units; and that a possibly non-commutative ring $R$ has unique factorization if it satisfies the uniqueness of factorization property for the quaternions, as stated on the wikipedia page....

Comment: ... If $a=xy=x'y'$ for $x,x'$ and $y,y'$ non-associate irreducibles in $S$, you can still look for a non-commutative $R$ so that $x,x',y,y'$ become reducible. But they have to become reducible *in the correct order*. Suppose that, as in your previous comment, $rstu=xy=x'y'=rtsu$ for $r,s,t,u$ irreducible. Unless $t$ and $s$ commute, this particular choice of $R$ is not a good one for the purposes of accomplishing unique factorization.

Answer (score 2):

$S = \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}] \subseteq \mathbb C = R$ or $S = K[x^2,x^3] \subseteq K[x] = R$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a non-integrally closed subring of a UFD (e.g. $\,\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]\subset \,\Bbb Z[(-1\!+\!\sqrt{-3})/2)\,$ is not a UFD, since UFDs are integrally closed (by the monic case of Rational Root Test).

**Remark** $\ $ Your idea of enlarging the ring to recover unique factorization is at the heart of Kummer's method of introducing "ideal numbers" in order to refine nonunique factorizations into unique factorizations. This was generalized in Kronecker's divisor theory (and, in another direction, by Dedekind's ideal theory).

Comment: @vuur I cannot make any sense of your prior remark.

Comment: Yeah that didn't make sense, sorry.